# Test for Subgroup Difference Compared to Test for Moderator

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, proportion, pooling

I have performed a proportional meta-analysis to evaluate the rate of procedural success for two medical procedures. The two procedures comprise the two subgroups in my meta-analysis (FNA and FNB). I am trying to understand whether or not there is a statistically significant difference between the rate of success between my subgroups.

This is the output from the meta-analysis using a REML random effects model, followed by meta-regression. The test for subgroup difference appears to show a statiistically significant difference between the subgroups (based on the common-effects difference for subgroups test), while the test for moderator shows no statistical significance.

Meta-Analysis:
[image]

Meta-Regression:
[image]

Any insight on how to reconcile these varying outcomes would be much appreciated. I have very minimal statistics background, so please let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The common effects model is a fixed effects model, which gives incorrect estimates and standard errors in the presence of heterogeneity (and you have lots of heterogeneity).

If you run your meta-regression as a fixed effects model, I imagine you'll get the same (incorrect) significant result.

Incidentally, please give us the code that you ran to get this result, and don't paste your code or as an image - it means I can't copy and paste parts of the code or output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I suspected that this was the case. I want to develop some insight into why significant heterogeneity produces these false positives when using fixed-effects models. Do you have any suggestions for reading on this topic?

And this is the code I used...

metaprop.EUSTA=metaprop(Adequate,Total,Author,data=NGS_by_Type,sm="PFT",method.tau="REML",subgroup=Type,pscale=1); metaprop.EUSTAreg <- metareg(metaprop.EUSTA,~Type)

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using one of the fixed effects models in the presence of heterogeneity. See https://research-information.bris.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/146974606/FixedEffectsPaperRev3.pdf for details of the three models which underlie meta-analysis.